# How to diagnose the slow responsiveness

Tags: linux, windows, performance, xeon, hp

I have a PC based on HP Z440:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm using Win 10 Pro and Ubuntu 20.04 on it. And it performs very well on high-load long-duration tasks like, for example, building AOSP 13 (full rebuild takes just 1 hour and 15 minutes). But in the "regular" tasks like even surfing the system settings or file explorer or opening dialogs in SolidWorks there are noticeable delays like 0.5-1 sec between the animations (and it's definitely not a GPU or display lag because sometimes "sand watches" appear).

P.S. CPU is replaced with a 22-cores one, but with the original one behaviour was the same.

It happens in both OS. How to diagnose it?

Benchmarks:

[image]
[image]
[image]